# How to pass (type *common.MapStr) to type []byte?

Tags: go

Sorry if the question is too newbie, as i just started to learn go yesterday.
I try to convert publishEvent into bytes, and compiler shown error like following:

```
cannot convert publishEvent (type *common.MapStr) to type []byte
```

Can anyone show me the way ?

Thank You.

```
    var parsed map[string]interface{}
    bytes := []byte(publishEvent) --->Error occur here
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &parsed)
    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the struct you are working with is `common.MapStr` from https://github.com/elastic/libbeat

`common.MapStr` is already a `map[string]interface{}` so I'm not sure why you are turing it into JSON, and then parsing it back into the same kind of structure, but if thats what you really want to do, replacing the error line with:

`bytes, err := json.Marshal(publishEvent)`

should work. You will get an error on the next line about redeclaring `err` so change it to:

`err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &parsed)`

Resulting in the following code (also added another error check):

```
var parsed map[string]interface{}
bytes, err := json.Marshal(publishEvent)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("error: ", err)
    // you'll want to exit or return here since we can't parse `bytes`
}
err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &parsed)
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println("error: ", err)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I want it to be in map, so i can call like fmt.Println(parsed["id.resp_h"].(string)) to get some value.

Comment: hi @ctcherry. is that possible to do string replace before  json.Marshal ?
As  i need to filter some unwanted string. Kindly help me.
Thank You

Comment: You can do find/replace on `[]bytes` with the stdlib `bytes.Replace` function is that what you mean? https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Replace